# Side length of a regular tetrahedron given the radius of the sphere tangent to its edges

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am working on a physics project where we have to build a container to protect a glass ornament when dropped from a high place. My design involves building a tetrahedron out of straws and putting the glass ornament inside of it.  I'm not sure what length to cut each side of the straw tetrahedron. I did some measurements and I estimated the radius of the sphere to be about 1.3. The tetrahedron has no "walls" where the ornament will touch at a single point. It is simply an empty frame made out of regular McDonald's straws, and the ornament will protrude out of each side a little bit, **thus there are no faces, only edges**. How can I find the best side length?

Comment: [Tetrahedron - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) Has all the formulae you need. I think your ornament will be midsphere of straw tetrahedron

Comment: The best I have seen was on an episode of "Modern Family." I think it was an egg being dropped. The smart daughter made a little parachute... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_Drop  I guess the scene with Alex and the parachute was an extra, after most of the show was over.

Answer (score 2):

Added: in the construction below, the point on an edge closest to the origin is at $(0,0,1),$ radius for this is exactly $1,$ therefore the edge length divided by $\sqrt 8$

===================================================================

one way to place a regular tetrahedron is at every other vertex of the cube with all vertices $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1).$ For example
$$ (-1,-1,-1) \; , \; \; \;  (-1,1,1) \; , \; \; \; (1,-1,1) \; , \; \; \; (1,1,-1) \; . \; \; \; $$
The edges are all length $\sqrt 8$

One triangle side is $$  x+y+z=1.  $$
The closest point to the origin in that plane is
$$ \left( \frac{1}{3},  \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3} \right) $$
with distance from the origin
$$  \frac{\sqrt 3}{3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3},$$
which is the radius of the inscribed sphere. Thus the radius is the edge length divided by $$ \sqrt{24} $$

Comment: OP said: "...and the ornament will protrude out of each side a little bit". You have calculated the radius of inscribed sphere touching all faces of tetrahedron, not the radius of insphere touching its edges.

Comment: @Oldboy I see what you mean. Added a note at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Your inscribed sphere is touching edges of tetrahedron, not its faces which do not exist in reality. The radius of the sphere touching **edges** of terahedron is known to be:

$$r=\frac{a}{\sqrt8}\iff a=2r\sqrt2\approx2.82r$$

Proving the formula is a fairly simple exercise.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Formulas_for_a_regular_tetrahedron

Comment: is 'a' the side length of the tetrahedron?

Comment: @user22333 Exactly.